# All images onload in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `<img>`s:

```
<img src="photo1.png">
<img src="photo2.png">
```

and I want it to run a function when **both of them** are finished loading.

```
$("img").load(blah);
function blah(e){
    var blah = "text";
}
```

But it doesn't work. It fires two times, since jQuery add `onload` to `<img>`s separately, which is not I wanted.

So how can I do that? Please help.

Comment: You can use `$("#1").load($("#2").load(blah));` adding them ids "1" and "2". Its ugly, and most ppl wouldn't like it, that's why i am posting that as comment, don't want get downwoted to hell.

Comment: @Kedor, I have to admit it... yes, it is very ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try it:

```
var imgs = $('img');
var imgs_count = imgs.length;
var imgs_loaded = 0;

imgs.load(function() {
    imgs_loaded++;

    if(imgs_loaded === imgs_count) {
        alert('All loaded!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Will this work even if the browser loads the image from its cache as opposed to by downloading it from the server?

Comment: You can see a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/bRzbj/) here. @maxedison: yeah, but you need put the code on `<head>` (inside of `$()`, of course!). **Edit**: you can check the `ImgElement.complete` data, if you need too.